# C++ Returning results from several threads into an array

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I've a pattern-matching program which takes as input a string and returns a string closely matched by a dictionary. Since the algorithm takes several seconds to run one match query, I am attempting to use multi-threading to run batch queries.

I first read in a file containing a list of queries and for each query dispatch a new thread to perform the matching algorithm, returning the results into an array using pthread_join.

However, I'm getting some inconsistent results. For example, if my query file contains the terms "red, green, blue", I may receive "red, green, green" as the result. Another run may generate the correct "red, green, blue" result. It appears to sometimes be writing over the result in the array, but why would this happen since the array value is set according to the thread id?

```
Dictionary dict;  // global, which performs the matching algorithm

void *match_worker(void *arg) {
    char* temp = (char *)arg;
    string strTemp(temp);
    string result = dict.match(strTemp);
    return (void *)(result.c_str());
}

void run(const string& queryFilename) {
    // read in query file
    vector<string> queries;
    ifstream inquery(queryFilename.c_str());
    string line;
    while (getline(inquery, line)) {
        queries.push_back(line);
    }
    inquery.close();

    pthread_t threads[queries.size()];
    void *results[queries.size()];
    int rc;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, match_worker, (void *)(queries[i].c_str()));
        if (rc) {
            cout << "Failed pthread_create" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &results[i]);
        if (rc) {
            cout << "Failed pthread_join" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
        cout << (char *)results[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string queryFilename = arg[1];
    dict.init();
    run(queryFilename);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: As suggested by Zac, I modified the thread to explicitly put the result on the heap:

```
void *match_worker(void *arg) {
    char* temp = (char *)arg;
    string strTemp(temp);
    int numResults = 1;
    cout << "perform match for " << strTemp << endl;
    string result = dict.match(strTemp, numResults);
    string* tmpResult = new string(result);
    return (void *)((*tmpResult).c_str());
}
```

Although, in this case, where would I put the delete calls? If I try putting the following at the end of the run() function it gives an invalid pointer error.

```
for (i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
    delete (char*)results[i];
}
```

Comment: What type is Dictionary? Is it thread safe?  It rather sounds like it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without debugging it, my guess is that it has something to do with the following:

```
void *match_worker(void *arg) 
{
    char* temp = (char *)arg;
    string strTemp(temp);
    string result = dict.match(strTemp); // create an automatic
    return (void *)(result.c_str()); // return the automatic ... but it gets destructed right after this!
}
```

So when the next thread runs, it writes over the same memory location you are pointing to (by chance), and you are inserting the same value twice (not writing over it).

You should put the result on the heap to ensure it does not get destroyed between the time your thread exits and you store it in your main thread.

With your edit, you are trying to mix things up a bit too much.  I've fixed it below:

```
void *match_worker(void *arg) 
{
    char* temp = (char *)arg;
    string strTemp(temp);
    int numResults = 1;
    cout << "perform match for " << strTemp << endl;
    string result = dict.match(strTemp, numResults);
    string* tmpResult = new string(result);
    return (void *)(tmpResult); // just return the pointer to the std::string object
}
```

Declare `results` as

```
// this shouldn't compile
//void* results[queries.size()]; 
std::string** results = new std::string[queries.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < queries.size(); ++i)
{
    results[i] = NULL; // initialize pointers in the array
}
```

When you clean up the memory:

```
for (i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) 
{
    delete results[i];
}
delete [] results; // delete the results array
```

That said, you would have a much easier time if you used the [C++11 threading templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) instead of mixing the C pthread library and C++.

Comment: @Aaron Edited to address your new issues.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the lifetime of the local variable `result` and the data returned by the member function `result.c_str()`. You make this task unnecessary difficult by mixing C with C++. Consider using C++11 and its threading library. It makes the task much easier:

```
std::string match_worker(const std::string& query);

void run(const std::vector<std::string>& queries)
{
    std::vector<std::future<std::string>> results;
    results.reserve(queries.size());
    for (auto& query : queries)
        results.emplace_back(
            std::async(std::launch::async, match_worker, query));
    for (auto& result : results)
        std::cout << result.get() << '\n';
}
```